# Ban domain extensions buddypress

Tags: php

can someone please help me out, I am using Buddypress/wordpress and i want to ban some domain extensions e.g .pl, .ru, .asia. i have tried the following functions which works for email domain but not extensions.

```
function my_bp_ban_domains( $result ) {
    $banned = array('.ru', '.pl');
    $error = 'God catch you brah !!!, Spammers are not welcome here, try your luck elsewhere.';
    $email = $result['user_email']; 
    $domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));
    if ( in_array($domain, $banned)) {
        $result['errors']->add('user_email', __($error, 'my_bp_ban_domains' ) );
    };
    return $result;
}

add_filter( 'bp_core_validate_user_signup', 'my_bp_ban_domains' );
```

Comment: Banning an entire country is never a good idea. Also, there are many ways around this.

Comment: is it true that every russians are spammers ?

Comment: All the spams i have got on my site is from .ru and .pl, they create multiples account in min and my group if full of their junk, I disable  group button and they still continue creating accounts. i have no choice but to block .pl and .ru.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work fine. I just go further and split domain using `.` and take last item in array:

```
function my_bp_ban_domains( $result ) {
    $banned = array('ru', 'pl');
    $error = 'Your email domain has been the source of spam. Please use another email address.';
    $email = $result['user_email']; 
    $domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));
    $ext = array_pop(explode(',',$domain));
    if ( in_array($ext, $banned)) {
        $result['errors']->add('user_email', __($error, 'my_bp_ban_domains' ) );
    };
    return $result;
}
```

Notice `$banned = array('ru', 'pl');` is changed a little (leading dots removed)

Comment: Hi FAngel,Thanks for your help the other time. I am just wondering if there is a way to Ban sub domain.  eg,  paul.noma@druid.example.com